# problem occuring when i am inserting date

Tags: mysql

while inserting date mysql server takes the year and day correctly but the month is defaultly taking januavary into the database.
i am using mysql server version 5.0.22
i am inserting the date though application.
the application was developed by using Springs web mvc frame-work and Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Can you display the mysql INSERT statement which is being used to insert the data into the database? This would indicate whether it is a malformed INSERT statement or whether it is a valid statement using incorrect data.

Once you know what is happening, you can track down where the problem really is. I would guess it is a faulty date-parsing function.

Another possibility is that the software is expecting the date in European format (dd-mm-yyyy) and getting the entry in US format (mm-dd-yyyy) or vice-versa. And this is causing parsing errors.

Comment: mysql date is always yyyy-mm-dd, but software could be misconfigured.

Comment: same problem with me so how could i configure my code in c# to give a yyyy-mm-dd format date?

Comment: same problem with me so how could i configure my code in c# to give a yyyy-mm-dd format date?